# Is $A=\{ (x,x^2): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ closed set?

Tags: general-topology

Is $A=\{ (x,x^2): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ closed set? I suppose that yes, but I have no idea how can i prove that. Or how show that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ is open.

Comment: How could you express this set with the continuous function $f(x,y)=y-x^2$?

Comment: On what topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $A$ is the graph of the continuous function $x \mapsto x^2$. Therefore it is closed. See this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367155/why-is-the-graph-of-a-continuous-function-to-a-hausdorff-space-closed).

Comment: So for any sets $A$ such that $A = \{(x,f(x)): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ where $f(x)$ is continuous function, $A$ ic closed?

Comment: @tomek Right. More generally, if $f$ is a continuous function from a topological space $X$ into an Hausdorff topological space $Y$, then the set $\{(x, f(x)) \mid x \in X\}$ is a closed subset of $X \times Y$.

Answer (score 7):

$f(x,y) = x^2-y$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

**How to do it:** Take any point $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ not in $A$, show that there exist an open ball around $y$ not intersecting $A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** This is just a parabola can you see it?

take a sequence  $z_n=(x_n,x_n^2)\in A \ni z_n\to z=(p,y)$

enough to show $z\in A$

since $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous so by sequential criterion for continuity we can say $p=x,y=x^2$ so $z\in A$

Comment: Of course, I know that this is parabola...

Comment: @Tomek Added details