# Proof verification for $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x, \sin(\frac{1}{x})) : x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}\}$ being an open set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I'm absolutely not sure if I got this right (I don't think I did), so it would be great if someone could check if my "proof" makes sense or not. I have to determine whether the set
$$B := \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \left\{\left(x, \sin\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)\right) : x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \right\}$$
is open or not.

What I did so far:

If $B$ is open, then the set $B^{\complement} := \left\{\left(x, \sin\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)\right) : x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \right\}$ should be closed.

Let's consider a singleton $b_n:=\{(x_n, \sin(\frac{1}{x_n}))\}$ where $x_n \ne 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

What I would like to do is to show that each such singleton is closed, so that each set $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x_n, \sin(\frac{1}{x_n}))\}$ is open, and therefore the union of all of them is open, that is: $B$ would be open. I'm not sure if it makes sense or not.

To show that a singleton is closed, we could let $y_n := (x_n, \sin(\frac{1}{x_n}))$ and let $\{y_n\} \subseteq b:=(x, \sin(\frac{1}{x}))$ be a convergent sequence (not sure if that's possible though, since $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is not well-known to be convergent). If that could be a thing, we would have $y_n = (x, \sin(\frac{1}{x}))$ (because $y_n \subseteq b$, with $b$ containing the single point $(x, \sin(\frac{1}{x}))$) and so $y_n \rightarrow (x, \sin(\frac{1}{x})) \in b$. Therefore, each $b_n$ would be closed and the union of all $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus \{(x_n, \sin(\frac{1}{x_n}))\}$ with $x_n \ne 0$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is open.

...Now that I read all this again, I feel like this is terribly wrong. Therefore, it might be that $B$ is not open. But if that's the case, I'm stuck at finding any counterexample of an open ball that would not be in $B$... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: look at the origin.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, $0$ is not included... but what should I conclude from that? I'm stuck (and not good at all with limits, obviously).

Comment: "... and therefore the union of all of them is open, that is: $B$ would be open." You're right that the union of all the $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \lbrace (x_n, \sin(\frac{1}{x_n})\rbrace$ would be open, but this union is equal to $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $B$. $B$ is the *intersection* of all these sets, but an infinite intersection of open sets need not be open.

Comment: The origin is in $B$. What about open balls around the origin?

Comment: @Arthur That's clever, I didn't even realize that. Does that mean that it would be sufficient to say "there exists $(x,y)=(0,0) \in B$ such that for all $r>0$, $B((x,y), r)$ is not included in $B$, so $B$ is not an open set"? How could I formally prove that this last sentence is true for all $r > 0$? I just began to study topology and I'm still very bad at these things.

Comment: Your observation is correct. I gave a hint in my answer. To formally prove this for all $r > 0$, take an arbitrary $r > 0$ and give a point contained in $B((x, y), r)$ but not in $B$.

Comment: @Bib-lost Thanks a lot for the help and all the answers, I'm going to study and read all this carefully :)

Answer (score 3):

> Now that I read all this again, I feel like this is terribly wrong.

Your feeling is correct. :P Singletons are **always** closed because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is T1.  That's one thing. The other is that $B$ is not a union of complements of singletons. Actually if $x, y$ are two different points, then $(X\backslash\{x\})\cup(X\backslash\{y\})=X$. So your $B$ is actually an **intersection** of complements. However infinite intersections need not be open.

Now your first step was correct. It is enough to show that the graph of a continous function is closed. For that see this:

[Why is the graph of a continuous function to a Hausdorff space closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367155/why-is-the-graph-of-a-continuous-function-to-a-hausdorff-space-closed)

Now the last problem is: the complement of the graph should be open in what? In codomain? In $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Denote by $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. What the article above proves is that the graph

$$Gr(f)=\{(x,f(x))\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}\}$$

is closed in $Y=\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$. So the complement $Y\backslash Gr(f)$ is open in $Y$. But $Y$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and thus the complement of graph is also open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

However note that $B\neq Y\backslash Gr(f)$ (thanks @Bib-lost for realizing that). They are almost equal, note that the graph is defined in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$. Thus

$$B=(Y\backslash Gr(f))\cup\{(0,r)\ |\ r\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

This set is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. That's because there is no open neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ which does not intersect the graph $Gr(f)$.

Comment: $Gr(f)$ is closed in $Y$, but definitely not in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as ${0} \times [-1, 1]$ lies in its closure.

Comment: @Bib-lost And where did I say that $Gr(f)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Just realized how stupid it was to say that $B$ is the union of singletons... Let's say it's because I'm tired as hell :) I'm going to check that article, thanks a lot!

Comment: @freakish You didn't, I'm afraid I do not understand your last sentence. What do you mean by "thus the graph is also open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Bib-lost The complement of graph is open in $Y$ and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as well. **Open**, not closed.

Comment: Ah, my bad. There was a typo. I've meant "the complement of graph".

Comment: I agree that $Y \setminus Gr(f)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This does not equal the set $B$ though, so I feel like the answer to OP's question should be negative.

Comment: @Bib-lost How is $Y\backslash Gr(f)$ not equal to $B$? What?

Comment: $B$ contains points like $(0, 2)$?

Comment: @Bib-lost Ah, you're right. Thanks, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence

$$
(\frac{1}{\pi}, 0), (\frac{1}{2\pi}, 0), (\frac{1}{3\pi}, 0), (\frac{1}{4\pi}, 0), \ldots
$$

is not contained in $B$, but its limit $(0, 0)$ is. Hence, $B$ is *not* open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. As freakish pointed out, $B \setminus (\lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \mathbb{R})$ is however open in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

B^c is not closed because (0,0) is not in B^c and every open nhood of (0,0) intersects B^c.  It is not open because the point p = (1, sin 1) is in B^c but no nhood of p is contained in B^c.  Exercise.  What is the closure of B^c?  What is its interior?