# Let $f,g:X \to Y$ be continuous, $Y$ Hausdorff. Show $\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f,g:X \to Y$ be continuous, $Y$ Hausdorff. Show $\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

Here is my attempt.

We seek to show $\{x: f(x)=g(x)\}^c \subset X$ is open. That is we aim to show if $x_0 \in \{x:f(x)=g(x)\}^c$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $U \subset \{x:f(x)=g(x)\}^c$. If $x_0 \in \{x:f(x)=g(x)\}^c$ then $f(x_0) \neq g(x_0)$ which are in $Y$ who is Hausdorff thus there exists open sets $V,W \subset Y$ that are disjoint with

$$f(x_0) \in V, g(x_0) \in W.$$

By continuity of $f$ their pre-images, $f^{-1}(V),f^{-1}(W) \subset X$ are open in $X$ and contain $x_0$. So do I take the union or intersection of their pre-images  to find my $U$ orrr?? Any hints greatly appreciated. Also, am I going about this the right way?? BTW this is exercise $\S$ $31.5$ out of Munkres.

Comment: The preimage of $V$ under f and the preimage of $W$ under g contain $x_0$. Both are open by continuity of f and g. Therefore their intersection is open and contains $x_0$. Their union might not be contained in your complement, but their intersection definitely is. Do you see why?

Comment: @Meneer-Beer yes because if your in their intersection then you're in both original open set which are disjoint thus they cannot be equal (as they have disjoint neighborhoods) hence the intersection is in the complement.

Comment: See also: [The set of points where two maps agree is closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/199617) (If your intention was mainly to get some feedback on your attempt, you should use the ([tag:solution-verification]) tag.)

Comment: And then there's two more answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285420/if-f-gx-to-y-are-continuous-and-y-is-t-2-then-x-in-x-fx-gx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going about this exactly the right way, you just need to finish off.

$V$ is an open neighbourhood of $f(x_0)$, $W$ an open neighbourhood of $g(x_0)$, and they are disjoint.

$f^{-1}(V)\cap g^{-1}(W)$ is an open neighbourhood of $x_0$ in $X$: let's call it $U$. If $x\in U$, then I know $f(x)\in V$ and $g(x)\in W$, and I know $V\cap W=\emptyset$, so it is not possible that $f(x)=g(x)$. That means: $$U\subseteq\{x\in X:f(x)\neq g(x)\}$$As desired.

Answer (score 2):

There is another concise approach with net.

Let $A = \{x \in X \mid f(x) = g(x)\}$ and show that $A = \overline{A}$.

**Proof:**
Suppose that $a \in \overline{A}$, then there exists a net $x = (x_{i})_{i \in I} \colon I \to A$ such that $\lim x = a$ (i.e. the net $x$ converges to $a$), by continuity at $a$, we have $\lim (f(x_{i}))_{i \in I} = f(a)$ and $\lim (g(x_{i}))_{i \in I} = g(a)$. Since $f(x_{i}) = g(x_{i})$ for each $i \in I$ and limits are unique in $Y$, hence
$$f(a) = \lim (f(x_{i}))_{i \in I} = \lim (g(x_{i}))_{i \in I} = g(a)$$
that means $a \in A$. Thus $\overline{A} \subseteq A$.

Comment: Nets are always another nice alternative to proving things about continuity or compactness or even here using the fact that nets converge to unique limits in Hausdorff spaces. +1 for that.