# Two equal functions on a topological space

Tags: general-topology, functions

Can anybody help please help me, I have to answer this problem in topology:

"Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions from the topological space $T$ into $\mathbb{R}$, with the usual topology. Show that $\{ x \in T \:| \:f(x) = g(x) \}$ is closed.

Also show that if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all x in some dense subset of $T$, then $f=g$ for all $x$ in $T$."

I hope someone can help me with this! Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Consider $f\times g\colon T\to \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171717/let-f-gx-rightarrow-mathbbr-continuous-functions-if-x-is-open-set-then). [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199617/the-set-of-points-where-two-maps-agree-is-closed) asks about a more general result where $\mathbb R$ is replaced by an arbitrary Hausdorff space. [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144480/show-that-the-set-x-in-a-b-fx-gx-is-closed-in-bbb-r) is a special case.

Comment: I should have written *almost a duplicate*. Now I've noticed in the [comments](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171717/let-f-gx-rightarrow-mathbbr-continuous-functions-if-x-is-open-set-then#comment394629_171717) to the other question that OP asks about functions on open subsets of $\mathbb R$. But it does not make too much difference, I think.

Comment: Another special case can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/442968/28900).

Answer (score 6):

Let $h:T\to\Bbb R$ be defined by $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. You should be able to show that $h$ is continuous. Your set is precisely the preimage under $h$ of the closed set $\{0\}$, so is closed by continuity of $h$.

If $S$ is a dense subset of $T$, then the closure of $S$ is $T$. But the closure of $S$ is the smallest closed subset of $T$ that contains $S$, and so if $S$ is a subset of the closed set in the first part (that is, if $f,g$ agree on $S$), then $T$ *is* the set from the first part, meaning $f=g$.

Comment: Ah, silly me. My suggestion above was unnecessary, but would work for the general case where $f,g\colon T\to Y$, $Y$ Hausdorff.

Comment: @Ted: Indeed, your method is more broadly applicable, but here, it felt a bit like swatting a fly with a Buick, to me. ;-)

Comment: I agree. I still would rather not give complete solutions when it seems 100% likely it's homework :P

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful :-) But what about the part where I have to show that it it a closed set? I know I probably have to show that the complement is open, but how do I do that?

Comment: @mathgirl310: Which "it" are you talking about showing to be closed? $\{0\}$? The preimage of $\{0\}$ under $h$? The closure of $S$?

Comment: I am talking about the set {x∈T|f(x)=g(x)}  :)

Comment: @mathgirl310: Gotcha. Given an arbitrary topological space $T$, what is your definition of continuity for functions $T\to\Bbb R$?

Comment: I suspect it is one of the following: (1) For all $x\in T$ and all $\epsilon>0$, there is some open $U\subseteq T$ with $x\in U$ such that $|h(x)-h(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $y\in U$. (2) For any open $x\in T$ and any open $V\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $h(x)\in V$, there is some open $U\subseteq T$ with $x\in U$ such that $h(U)\subseteq V$. (3) The pre-image under $h$ of any $\Bbb R$-open set is $T$-open. (4) The pre-image under $h$ of any $\Bbb R$-closed set is $T$-closed. Definition (4) is the one I hinted at in my answer. You should be able to show they are all equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

A nicer result can be seen as following:

> **Theorem:** For any pair $f,g$ of continuous mappings of a space $X$ into a Hausdorff space $Y$, the set $\{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

Proof: We shall show that the set $A=\{x \in X: f(x)\not=g(x)\}$ is open. For every $x \in A$ we have $f(x)\not=g(x)$; hence there exist in $Y$ open sets $U_1, U_2$ such that $f(x)\in U_1$, $g(x)\in U_2$ and $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$. The set $f^{-1}(U_1) \cap g^{-1}(U_2)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ contained in $A$.

And hence,

> **Corollary:** For any pair $f,g$ of continuous mappings of a space $X$ into a Hausdorff space $Y$ with $f(x)=g(x)$ for any $x\in S$, where $S$ a dense subset  of $X$, then for any $x\in X$, $f(x)=g(x)$.

Proof: It is clearly to see that $S \subset \{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$. By the above theorem, we can conclude that $\overline{S} \subset \{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$, and hence $X = \{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$.