# Show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be both continuous. Supose that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $ x \in D$, where $D\subseteq\mathbb R$ is dense. Show that $f(x)=g(x)$, for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Id like a hint to solve this question.

Comment: Consider $h^{-1}(\{0\})$ where $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$.

Comment: Letting $\mathcal D$ be the set of dense subsets of $\Bbb R$, is the hypothesys $$(\forall D\in \mathcal D)(\forall x\in D)(f(x)=g(x))$$ or is it $$(\exists D\in \mathcal D)(\forall x\in D)(f(x)=g(x))?$$

Comment: Seems to me that it is the latter.

Comment: A more general version of this question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/408706/28900).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more hint:

Define $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$. For any given $y$ and $\delta$, there exists $x \in D$, such that $|x-y| < \delta$. Now, for prove that for any given $\epsilon$, since $h$ is continuous, $h(y) - h(x) = h(y) <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any $x_n \to x$ you have $f(x) = \lim_n f(x_n)$ and $\lim_n g(x_n) = g(x)$.
For each $x$, is it possible to select a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $\lim_n f(x_n) = \lim_n g(x_n)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $Y$ a Hausdorff space. Then the set $\mathrm{diffker}(f,g)$ of points $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ is closed in $X$. For its complement is open: if $x\notin\mathrm{diffker}(f,g)$ then $f(x)\neq g(x)$ and $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have distinct open neighborhoods in $Y$, taking the intersection of their preimages gives a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ contained in $\mathrm{diffker}(f,g)$. If $\mathrm{diffker}(f,g)$ is dense in $X$, then $\mathrm{diffker}(f,g)=\overline{\mathrm{diffker}(f,g)}=X$. Now put $X=Y=\mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $(f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed and $D \subset (f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$.